# Adding a second label to colorbar

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I have an `imshow` plot with a colorbar. I want two labels in the colorbar, one on the left side and the other one on the right side.

This is the mve:

```
V = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])  # Just a sample array

plt.imshow(V, cmap = "hot", interpolation = 'none')
clb = plt.colorbar()
clb.set_label("Firstlabel", fontsize=10, labelpad=-40, y=0.5, rotation=90)
#clb.set_label("SECONDLABEL") # This is the label I want to add
plt.savefig("Example")
```

This produces:

[image]

I want a second label on the right side of the colorbar. If I use the commented line a second colorbar is added to my plot, and that is not what I want. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two `label` objects, but you could add a second label using `clb.ax.text`.

Also, note that to move the first label to the left hand side, you could use `clb.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')` rather than `labelpad=-40`

So, using lines:

```
clb = plt.colorbar()

clb.set_label("Firstlabel", fontsize=10, y=0.5, rotation=90)
clb.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')

clb.ax.text(2.5, 0.5, "SECONDLABEL", fontsize=10, rotation=90, va='center')
```

Produces this figure:

[image]